# How to enable sqlite3 FTS5 extension in python (on windows)?

Tags: python, sqlite, fts5

I am trying to use FTS5 from sqlite3 in python, but I see that the extension is not enabled. Online, I can only find tutorials on how to enable this on linux or mac. Is there an easy way to enable FTS5 on windows?

(I have only recently started to learn coding and do not know much about running comands from prompt, so a beginner friendly explanation would be highly appreciated :))

Thank you very much!